# Why doesn't this URL rewrite work?

Tags: .htaccess

This is a page on my domain: www.mydomain.com/en/stats.php

I want it to look like this: www.mydomain.com/en/statistics/players

This is pretty simple to accomplish, but for some reason the htaccess code below doesn't work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/statistics/players stats.php [R=301,L,QSA]
```

I get a 404 error when I try to open the SEO-friendly version. The page opens fine when I use the regular URL. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For RegEx `^` means begin of line, but your URL starts with '''/en''' so it will not match. try removing the `^/` from your code, or make your regex more precise `^/en/foobar/baz /en/foo.php`

Answer (score 0):

I think it needs to be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^en/statistics/players en/stats.php [QSA]
```

The `R=301` means it will perform a redirect instead of a rewrite and try to redirect to /stats.php which doesnt exists I guess.

The `L` flag means that this is the last rewrite rule that will be processed for this request, which in this case I doubt is what you want. If there are rewrite rules further down for /en/stats.php they wont be processed.

Comment: Right. The 301 was there by mistake. I've removed it as it's not necessary. But it still doesn't work, whether I use your version or not.

Comment: You need to make sure you are taking the en part of the URL into account too. I haev tweaked my answer though not 100% sure this will work may need more tweaking but I cant test it

Answer (score 0):

The URL might not have a leading slash. Try without or optional slash. Additionally, you must check for the leading `en`, when you anchor your pattern at the beginning

```
RewriteRule ^/?en/statistics/players /en/stats.php
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked in the end is the following:

```
RewriteRule en/statistics/players en/stats.php [NC,L]
```